# How to add Google Voice Search in Magento?

Tags: catalogsearch, search, advanced-search, google-api

> How to add google voice search in magento.

**Is there any api for this.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to implement this is in Chrome (webkit) where it only takes some HTML attributes on an input type.

For the small search form input in the top of the page that would be something like below. You can read more about that [here](http://www.labnol.org/software/add-speech-recognition-to-website/).

```
<input id="search" type="text" name="q" value="" class="input-text" maxlength="50" x-webkit-speech>
```

On other browsers it might take more effort. Since there isn't a standard browser API yet you will need to capture the audio of the user using either some HTML5 or Flash application and send it of to the Google Speech Recognition API.

ALthough I've never used it this library looks promising  http://mikepultz.com/2013/07/google-speech-api-full-duplex-php-version/